# Uniform distribution cdf expected value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given that $X_1, \ldots ,X_n$ are independent random variables, of identical distribution, from a uniform distribution $U(0,10)$, let $\hat{F}(t)$ denotes cdf estimated on a basis of $X_1 \ldots X_n$ in a point t.
Find expected value of $\hat{F}(4)$ and variance.

Will $EX$ simply will be $E(0.4)=0.4$? What about the variance?

Comment: It's better to use $\hat{F}(t)$  instead of $F(t)$ to represent an estimator.

Comment: What kind of estimator are you using? The empirical distribution function?

Comment: Yes empirical dist function

Comment: Sorry but what exactly happened [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1918082)?

Comment: I reached a conclusion that this question was poorly state i.e. wasn't sufficiently well written to present the matter of the question itself likewise my way of thinking. Appreciate your concern.

Comment: Not sure that silently deleting your question was the proper thing to do. (Not sure that answering comments without using @ is proper either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empirical distribution function is given by
$$
\hat F_n(t)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nI_{\{X_i\le t\}}.
$$
Using the linearity of the expectation and the identical distributions,
$$
\operatorname E\hat F_n(t)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname EI_{\{X_i\le t\}}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nP(X_i\le t)=P(X_1\le t).
$$
The variance is given by
$$
\operatorname{Var}\hat F_n(t)=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}I_{\{X_i\le t\}}=\frac1nP(X_i\le t)P(X_i>t)
$$
since $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on where does the variance comes from?

Comment: @mkropkowski Let's say I have an indicator $I$ which is $1$ when $A$ occurs, and $0$ otherwise. The expected value is obviously $P(A)$ (abusing some notation). Now, obviously $I = I^2$, so that $\text{Var}(I) = \mathbb{E}[I^2] - (\mathbb{E}[I])^2 = P(A)-P(A)^2 = P(A)[1-P(A)]$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, 
$$\hat{F}(4) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n I(X_i \leq 4),$$
where $I$ stands for the indicator function.

By the i.i.d. assumption on $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, $I(X_1 \leq 4), \ldots, I(X_n \leq 4)$ are i.i.d. 
Bernoulli($p$) random variables. Can you determine $p$ and then proceed?

---

For simplicity, denote $I(X_i \leq 4)$ by $Y_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Then
$$p = P(Y_i = 1) = P(X_i \leq 4) = 0.4$$
since $X_i \sim U(0, 10)$. Therefore,
$E(Y_i) = p = 0.4$, $\text{Var}(Y_i) = p(1 - p) = 0.4 \times 0.6 = 0.24$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

Finally, by independence assumption,
$$E(\hat{F}(4)) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n E(Y_i).$$
$$\text{Var}(\hat{F}(4)) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n \text{Var}(Y_i).$$

I think this will be detailed enough.

Comment: No i think i need something more to understand this

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\hat{F}(t) = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_i\mathbb{I}(X_i \leq t)$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ denotes the indicator function.

The expected value of $\hat{F}$ at each $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is 
$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{F}(t)] = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_i\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}(X_i \leq t)]$$
and it is easy to see that the expected value of an indicator is the probability of the indicator being equal to $1$, i.e., 
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}(X_i \leq t)] = \mathbb{P}(X_i \leq t)\text{.}$$
The variance can be approached similarly, due to independence.